# Search serverside datatables -- invalid JSON response

Tags: json, search, datatable, serverside-datatable

I have a serverside datatable. The table is working and displaying fine and I used some functions to change the data displayed in the table. The problem is in search box.

The data that I modified is `date`. the data is stored in the database as `yyyy-mm-dd` then I modified using javascript function to convert it to `dd mm yyyy` format

```
...
{
   "data": "created_date", // ex. 2023-05-10
   render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
      return changeDate(data); // return 10 May 2023
   }
},
...
```

when I want to search 'may', it doesn't work and there is a warning invalid JSON response. Do you know how to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to help you effectively. You can [edit] your question. To start with, can you: (a) show us the full error message; (b) show us the invalid JSON (as formatted text). See also [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: Also, what does "_a serverside datatable_" mean, here? Do you mean a table that uses `serverSide: true`? If so, then bear in mind how this works: it means that your search term `may` is sent to the server - and your server is responsible for finding records where the date is for May (the month is `05`).